# UIViewController & UIView: respond to screen changes from outside the object?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

## What I'm trying to do

I'm trying to detect:

- when a new `UIViewController` has entered the screen
- when a `UIViewController` has left the screen
- when a `UIView` has been added to the screen
- when a `UIView` has left the screen

**Key Point:** I'm trying to detect all these changes from the *outside*.

Meaning: I don't want to have to respond to these changes from existing funcs inside the classes themselves, I want to be able to observe them from an outside class and react accordingly.

**Bonus points:** If we don't have to know ANY info about ANY of the `UIView`s or `UIViewControllers` beforehand, and we don't have to add ANY code to the views themselves, that would be amazing.

My initial thoughts is these involve KVO and listening to the UIViewController's view's window property and similar things.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a `BaseViewController` class that inherits from `UIViewController` and overrides the `viewDidAppear(_:)` and `viewDidDisappear(_:)` methods. Within each of those you could post a notification.
Then make all UIViewControllers that you care about inherit from `BaseViewController`.

You still have to add code to all your ViewControllers, but it would just be an inheritance from a single class.

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        // viewDidAppear notification
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        // viewDidDisappear notification
    }
}
```

Same idea with a `BaseView` class.

```
class BaseView: UIView {
    override func addSubview(_ view: UIView) {
        super.addSubview(view)
        // notification
    }

    override func willRemoveSubview(_ subview: UIView) {
        super.willRemoveSubview(subview)
        // notification
    }
}
```